# r - generate a step response in R - similar to MATLAB/GNU Octave example

Tags: r, matlab, octave, control-theory

I would like to complete the step response example from GNU Octave/MATLAB in R. [Extras: Generating a Step Response in MATLAB](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?aux=Extras_step) is the source of the example.

in R

```
M <- 1; K <- 10; B <- 2; num <- 1; den <- c(M, B, K)
```

How do you define the transfer function in R?

How do you get the step response of that system in R?

in GNU Octave/MATLAB

```
M = 1;  % units of kg
K = 10; % units of N/m
B = 2;  % units of N-s/m
num = 1;
den = [M B K];
sys = tf(num,den)
step(sys);

    % sys =

   % 1
   % --------------
   % s^2 + 2 s + 10

   % Continuous-time transfer function.
```

[image]

Comment: Check out [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) under **Forecasting and Univariate Modeling**, it states: "Transfer function models are provided by the arimax function in the TSA package, and the arfima function in the arfima package." Your example is an `AR` model, which is a subset of the `ARIMAX` models this packages can handle.

Comment: @aichao  Thank you for pointing out that link to me, but the transfer function that is addressed in the forecasting packages is not the same transfer function used in control systems design and analysis. For more information, check out these: [link1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function) and [link2](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/MATLAB).

Comment: yes, I understand, but that is a matter of converting between the Laplace domain and the Z domain. I don't believe you will find a *controls* package in R that is like matlab.

Comment: Can you use Python?

Comment: @aichao  Thank you for the response. When I get a chance, I will work on converting portions of the GNU Octave `control` package to R to provide this missing functionality in R.

Comment: @percusse  Thank you for your question. I am looking for a R solution rather than a Python one. I know that Python also has this functionality, but I want this to be possible in R too.